# How to configure .bashrc for git-for-windows?

Tags: windows-7, bash, git

I used Git Bash for Windows with Version 1.9.5 on my Windows 7 (64bit). I added a `.bashrc` and a `.gitconfig` in my `%USERPROFILE%` folder (`C:\Users\<USERNAME>\`). Everything worked fine.

Now i updated to the latest Version 2.5.0 (64bit) and these files are ignored. The Git Config file moved to `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`. But I couldn't find the location for my `.bashrc`.

I tried to rename it to `.profile`, tried to move it to `C:\ProgramData\Git\config`, but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32189255/5147101